# Laravel : Can't display more than one table

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm getting data of a specific contact using his `id` as following :

```
<span wire:click="confirmContactEdit({{$contact->id}})" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
            
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">

<path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z"></path>
</svg>

</span>
```

When displaying his infos, I only have info of the **contact** table, and not the **entreprise** table. And when I remove `Contact $contact` and `$this->contact = $contact;` I have the infos of the entreprise displaying alone without the contact. **So either one of them is displaying at at time.**

Contact.php

```
public function confirmContactEdit(Contact $contact, Entreprise $entreprise){        
    $this->contact = $contact;
    $this->entreprise = $entreprise;
    $this->confirmingContactAdd = true;
}
```

Comment: You are not passing $enterprise as parameter on your function caller.

Comment: In `confirmContactEdit` ?

Comment: your confirmContactEdit method require two parameters and in the blade you are only passing one

Comment: @Prospero Ok so how do I pass or separate multiple parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method is required with two parameters but through the blade you're only want to pass it one you can do this

```
 // in the blade
<span wire:click="confirmContactEdit({{$contact->id}})" wire:loading.attr="disabled">

 // in component
public function confirmContactEdit(Contact $contact = null, $entreprise = null){     
  if($contact)   
    $this->contact = $contact;
  if($enterprise)
    $this->entreprise = $entreprise;

  $this->confirmingContactAdd = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it gives me 404 error.

Comment: I'm sorry, don't see your comment about the 404 . I'm updated my answer

Comment: No error now, but I still can see only contact data. Not entreprise data.

Comment: @AlyaKra I show you how to pass in blade only one parameter without modify the component method. If you are passing the enterprise as parameter from blade, just do it!